# Iterating over an array and appending its values to a dictionary in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, backend

I am trying to iterate over an dictionary that has values in form of array those values I want to put in a dictionary I am confused as to what should I do to obtain this

Here is the data that I want to iterate over :

```
{
t: ["20181019,20181022,...."],
o: ["180.34,189.45,..."],
h: ["180.99,181.40,..."],
l: ["178.57,177.56,...."],
c: ["179.85 ,178.75,...."]
}
```

Here is what the end product should look like :

```
[
    { time: '20181019', open: 180.34, high: 180.99, low: 178.57, close: 179.85 },
    { time: '20181022', open: 180.82, high: 181.40, low: 177.56, close: 178.75 },
    { time: '20190509', open: 193.31, high: 195.08, low: 191.59, close: 194.58 },
]
```

Comment: What have you tried? It is essential we hear your thoughts on it, so we can help you. If you do not think about the problem and obtain answers online, then you will not learn stuff. Add whatever no matter how little about your approach to the problem

Comment: I have tried mapping it but still running into problems

Comment: Ok. You used `.map()`? Please add to the question. You will need to break the string too.  Also will all the strings have equal numbers(/commas?. Add such details

Comment: Do each array have same lengths or different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code.

```js
var data = {
  t: ["20181019,20181022"],
  o: ["180.34,189.45"],
  h: ["180.99,181.40"],
  l: ["178.57,177.56"],
  c: ["179.85 ,178.75"]
}

var res = [];

const open = data.o.toString().split(",");
const high = data.h.toString().split(",");
const low = data.l.toString().split(",");
const close = data.c.toString().split(",");

data.t.toString().split(",").forEach((item, index) => {
  res.push({
    time : item,
    open : open[index],
    high: high[index],
    low: low[index],
    close: close[index]
  });
})

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve the result using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const obj = {
  t: ["20181019,20181022"],
  o: ["180.34,189.45"],
  h: ["180.99,181.40"],
  l: ["178.57,177.56"],
  c: ["179.85 ,178.75"],
};

const dict = { t: "time", o: "open", h: "high", l: "low", c: "close" };

const tempObj = Object.keys(obj).forEach((k) => (obj[k] = obj[k][0].split(",")));

const result = Array.from({ length: obj.t.length }, (_, i) => {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
        acc[dict[k]] = k === "t" ? v[i] : +v[i];
    return acc;
  }, {});
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: its showing `Uncaught TypeError: obj[k][0].split is not a function`

Comment: as with all other answers

Comment: i am getting my data from this [wesbite](https://priceapi.moneycontrol.com/techCharts/techChartController/history?symbol=TCS&resolution=1D&from=1598101077&to=1632229137)

Comment: You misspelled the question. The `data.t` variable is an array but you typed a string `["20181019,20181022,...."]`. it should have been like this `['20181019','20181022',...."]`. Chek this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-izuyv8?file=index.js)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the quick solution:

```js
const data = {
  t: ['20181019,20181022,....'],
  o: ['180.34,189.45,...'],
  h: ['180.99,181.40,...'],
  l: ['178.57,177.56,....'],
  c: ['179.85 ,178.75,....'],
};

let prepared = {};
Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
  prepared[key] = data[key][0].split(',');
});

const res = prepared.t.map((tVal, index) => {
  return {
    time: tVal,
    open: prepared.o[index],
    high: prepared.h[index],
    low: prepared.l[index],
    close: prepared.c[index],
  };
});

console.log(res);
```